Set of representatives vs Teichmüller representatives
Say $K$ is a local field (complete wrt a discrete valuation with finite residue field, or if you want perfect residue field). Denote its residue field by $k$ where $k= \mathcal{O}_K / \mathcal{M}_K.$ What is the difference between a set of representatives and the set of Teichmüller representatives for $k$? Also what exactly is the Teichmüller character? I would appreciate an answer with good definitions and examples & non-examples. Thank you.


I am not sure what you mean by "set of representatives", but my guess is that given $\overline{x} \in k$, any element $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ satisfying $$x \equiv \overline{x} \mod \mathcal{M}_K$$ can be called a representative of $\overline{x}$. If you fix a representative for each element in $k$, that set can be called a "set of representatives".
The set of Teichnumller representatives is a specific set of representatives. For each $\overline{x} \in k$, there is a unique element $w(\overline{x}) \in \mathcal{O}_K$ satisfying $$w(\overline{x}) \equiv \overline{x} \mod \mathcal{M}_K$$ (i.e. it is a representative/lift of $\overline{x}$), and also $$w(\overline{x})^p = w(\overline{x}).$$ The existence/uniqueness comes from Hensel's lemma. This specific set of representatives is the set of Teichmuller representatives.
Note that the map $k^{\times} \to \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ defined by $$\overline{x} \to w(\overline{x})$$ is a character; this comes from uniqueness in Hensel's lemma, and that the solutions to $w(\overline{x})^p = w(\overline{x})$ is closed under multiplication. This is called the Teichmuller character.


The Teichmuller representatives are just an example of a set of representaives for the residue field. When a local field $K$ has a residue field $k = \mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m_K$ with order $q$, the polynomial $x^q - x$ splits into a product of linear factors in $k[x]$ with distinct roots in $k$, so by Hensel's lemma each coset mod $\mathfrak m_K$ contains a unique root of $x^q - x$: for each $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$, there's a unique number $\omega$ in $\mathcal O_K$ such that $\omega^q = \omega$ and $\omega \equiv \alpha \bmod \mathfrak m_K$.
We denote that $\omega$ by $\omega(\alpha)$, so when $\alpha \in \mathfrak m_K$ we have $\omega(\alpha) = 0$, and when $\alpha \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak m_K$ we have $\omega(\alpha) = 1$.  The roots of $x^q = x$ are easily seen to be closed under multiplication, which implies $\omega(\alpha\beta) = \omega(\alpha)\omega(\beta)$:  both sides are roots of $x^q = x$ and are congruent to $\alpha\beta \bmod \mathfrak m_K$, so they must be equal by the uniqueness in Hensel's lemma. We call $\omega(\alpha)$ the Teichmuller representative of $\alpha$.
Example.  When $K = \mathbf Q_3$, $\omega(\alpha) = 0$ when $\alpha \in 3\mathbf Z_3$, $\omega(\alpha) = 1$ when $\alpha \in 1 + 3\mathbf Z_3$, and $\omega(\alpha) = -1$ when $\alpha \in 2 + 3\mathbf Z_3$.
Each element of $k^\times$ contains a unique element of $\mathcal O_K^\times$ that is a nonzero root of $x^q = x$, meaning it is a root of $x^{q-1} = 1$.  So to each $c \in k^\times$ there is one $(q-1)$-th root of unity $\chi(c)$ in $\mathcal O_K^\times$ such that $\chi(c) \bmod \mathfrak m_K = c$.  We call $\chi : k^\times \to \mathcal O_K^\times$ the Teichmuller character of $k$.
Example.  The residue field of $\mathbf Q_3$ is a field $k$ of order $q = 3$, and $\chi : k^\times \to \{1,-1\}$ by $\chi(1 \bmod 3) = 1$ and $\chi(2 \bmod 3) = -1$.
Example.  The residue field of $\mathbf Q_5$ is a field $k$ of order $q = 5$, so $\mathbf Z_5^\times$ contains $4$th roots of unity. There's a unique such number that is $2 \bmod 5$ and is not $\pm 1$, so it must be a $5$-adic square root of $-1$. Call this $i$, so $i \equiv 2 \bmod 5$.  Explicitly,
$i = 2 + 5 + 2\cdot 5^2 + 5^3 + 3\cdot 5^4 + \cdots$.  Also $-i \equiv 3 \bmod 5$, and explicitly
$-i = 3 + 3\cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 5^2 + 3\cdot 5^3 + 5^4 + \cdots$.
We have $\chi : k^\times \to \{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ in $\mathbf Z_5^\times$ by $\chi(1 \bmod 5) = 1$, $\chi(2 \bmod 5) = i$, $\chi(3 \bmod 5) = -i$, and $\chi(4 \bmod 5) = -1$.
